# Find Delta only records in ArcGIS (SDE)

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, objectid

We have spatial layers in ArcSDE with objectid as unique value, I've taken this data to another platform & migrated data to cloud.

Now, after months, back in ArcSDE and want to migrate new data (huge data), but want to take only DELTA data to cloud, i.e. any new records, deleted records and modified records, so I can insert new records into existing data in cloud, delete records which have been deleted in source, and update records which are modified in source.

So, my questions are:

1. Is OBJECTID in feature class in SDE are reliable to calculate whether they are new, modified & deleted? Can I compare earlier export of the data & find objectid's?
2. What are options in SDE or outside (examaple: PostGres) to check only delta records?
3. Do I need to separately enable in SDE to capture delta or create additional fields to capture D,I & U records?  Our geodatabase is versioned, and multiple people are creating versions and being posted to production regularly.

Comment: You've left out:  The version of ArcGIS in the source and cloud datasets, the version of your database, whether you have a working unique key across the two databases (something other than objectid), how the data was exported, how the data was imported,...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really provided enough information to answer your questions, but this will get you started:

1. No, the registered rowid cannot be trusted **unless** you have eliminated ArcGIS from the insert process (the target instance is not geodatabase enabled, or you used unsupported means to populate the tables in the cloud copy)
2. If you've really been posting data to the business table, then there is no way to use the long-transaction versioning model to retroactively capture deltas (though if you had archiving enabled, you could use that)
3. Change detection cannot be applied retroactively outside the versioning model (the replication process preserves deltas in the An/Dn tables, and requires GUID columns to preserve linkage)

What you need to do is identify all the rows in the cloud copy, and compare them to the existing instance (just features which have been posted).  I've cut corners in this regard by using a hashing function, comparing the md5sum hash of the editable fields in each row (without the rowid) to the {rowid,hash} of the source table.  If you port the cloud data back, you might be able to use the tools in the [Data Comparison Toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-data-comparison-toolset.htm) to identify deltas (Caution: if they haven't been lost already, you might lose objectids when the data is moved back!)

You're in a very risky position because you failed to create a reliable feature identifier before copying the data to the cloud instance.  If you had added a "OldRowId" column, populating it with the value from objectid **before** creating your cloud clone, you'd have a certain way to distinguish features.  Now you need to spend time trying to determine if the objectid column can serve this purpose, or if your linkage is lost (in which case you need to find a new way to re-associate the rows in the two instances).

Comment: Thanks Vince..appreciate your time to answer my question. Yes, objectid's are taken from sde to cloud when migrated, that was my primary question, how to find delta when I have OBJECTID brought from SDE, are they reliable to find differences between previous data & current data of the same layer. I need definite process to follow.. trying SDE tools to detect or compare features